# How do i remove the current text in the text field when switching frames

Tags: java, text, field, textfield

I have 2 frames, one has a button that will lead to the second frame. The second frame has a text field. What I did was I added an actionlistener to my button that will make its visible false and make the 2nd frame's visible to true. But my problem is that I just make them visible/invisible so if I typed anything on the textfield on my second frame then click the return to 1st frame button, the text is still in there if i click the go to 2nd frame button on the 1st frame. Is there any code to completely terminate the frame instead of the set.Visible(false) so that when I return to my textfield it is clean

Comment: Are you talking about a webpage (HTML and JavaScript), a Windows Form application, or something else all together?  More details are needed indicating what technology stack you are using.

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot to tell what language, its Java, I made those in GUI

Comment: Are these JFrames? Are you using JTextFields? You seem to be withholding much information from us -- why? Can you show code that you've tried? Explain in greater detail how it's not working? The better information you can provide to us, usually the better we can help you. And if you are talking about JTextFields, why not simply call `setText("")` on the JTextField that you want to clear its text?

Answer (score 1):

> I have 2 frames,

An application should only have a single main JFrame

> The second frame has a text field.

The second window should be a JDialog, not a JFrame.

> Is there any code to completely terminate the frame instead of the set.Visible(false) so that when I return to my textfield it is clean

No. You have two choices:

1. Just recreate the JDialog every time you click on the button and the componets will display their default values.
2. Add code to reset all the components to their initial state.